# Make the List to be responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Goal:
Make the list (ul and its li) to be responsive design in relation to the screen's width.

Problem:
I don't know how to solve it.

Info:
*You need to take account to amount of li in each ul list. Different responsive design depends on the width of the ul.
*Each ul can be random from 1 to 10 li or more.

JSBin:
https://jsbin.com/xibalahave/edit?html,css,output

Thank you!

---

```css
.aaa ul.listlist {
  margin: 10px 0 16px;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.aaa ul.listlist li {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 24px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">
  <ul class="listlist">
    <li>1Test 1</li>
    <li>1Test 2</li>
    <li>1Test 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div class="aaa">
  <ul class="listlist">
    <li>1Test 1</li>
    <li>1Test 2</li>
    <li>1Test 3</li>
    <li>1Test 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div class="aaa">
  <ul class="listlist">
    <li>1Test 1</li>
    <li>1Test 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean, but try adding `flex-wrap: wrap` on your ul class which will make the items wrap to the next row if they would overflow the page horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `flexwrap: wrap;` to the container of the `li`, it will allow the child-elements (here, `li`), to go to another line. I invite you to learn about the flexbox and all their properties, this is very helpful for the responsive design! Check it out [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.listlist{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```